# Show google map in auto complete list

Tags: google-maps

I am using google map api auto complete in my form
I want to add google map in auto complete list. Attaching image what I want. 
http://demo.bigbeehive.com/orientplay/Untitled-1.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

For the input field to complete cover the top you can use a custom css. But I am not a great css guy, so that may be something for another question :P